# Does Apachr Solr use Taxonomy or CCK fields for faceted search?

Tags: search

I'm trying to put together a simple faceted search block using Solr. Search with Solr works, but I'm unsure of what's required for creating a block of search properties for faceted search.

For example, my content is for accommodation, so I want to be able to search by price range, capacity and location. Price range and capacity data are already populated as CCK fields, but location is set up as a hierarchical taxonomy.

I'm wondering what Solr requires for me to implement a simple, faceted search block. Does it use CCK fields for search properties or Taxonomy? Or have I misunderstood how faceted search blocks for Solr are built?

Comment: You did not get the point, it makes a difference whether you are asking for D6 or D7. On D7 there is Facet API on D6 there is hook_apachesolr_facets, with basic facet block functionality being already built in the apachesolr_search module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, apachesolr.module 6.x and its friends can facet on taxonomy and cck text fields (with certain limitations). You just need to enable the desired facets in the settings, having made sure that the vocabulary is actually connected to your content type in the vocabulary settings.

For price range / any numeric range faceting I have not found a working contrib module. There is a module though, http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_facetbuilder which allows you to build at least categorized facets for your numeric values.

Comment: Interesting - I've spent a bit of time in the settings for Solr in both 6 and 7 and have been unable to found anything intuitive that appears to relate to facet settings and connecting them to taxonomy and CCK fields. If the setup for facets is in the settings, though, I'll check again and see what I've missed out.

Thanks for the module recommendation - I'll take a look.